# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, referenceerror

I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in [this](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js) jQuery plugin (jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js), and I'm not sure what's wrong.  Can someone point me in the right directions? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are loading jquery first.

Comment: Include the jQuery in your project please.

Comment: yes I read that in someone else post, because trying to switch from jquery 1.6.2 to an 1.9.x or higher. And the jQuery site suggest to use jquery-migrate because there is some of the functionalities that they took out from the older version. So I'm not do I include jquery-migrate in place of the new versions of jquery or do I have to include both?

Comment: jquery-migrate is not jquery. It's only the migration code - it allows you to use things that were deprecated, removed or made to work differently in newer versions of jquery - but it isn't a replacement jquery by itself.

Comment: okay, so does this means I also need to include the newer version of jQuery that I want right?

Comment: why the downvotes?  what's wrong w/ you guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery-migrate, as it says, simply allows you to use "APIs and features removed from jQuery core". It contains only those functions - it does not contain the *rest* of the jquery library. Thus: you need to include jquery (whichever version you want to use), and then after that, include jquery-migrate.

Comment: hi would you help me with another problem related to jquery marquee plugin?